# Issue with custom actions : Visual studio (2008) installer project

Tags: custom-action

I Need to do an action, while installing an application using VS installer, based on the user input. I have created a new text-box input screen in user interface editor and followed the below URL to do a custom action.

http://steptodotnet.blogspot.in/2012/10/visual-studio-package-and-development.html

I could do an action in the install() of installer1.cs class, But I would like to do the action based on the text input by user. Can someone please help me to solve it.

Thanks in  advance
Sebastian

Answer (score 0):

The canned VS setup dialog you use should have an uppercase property name associated with the entry field. TEXTBOXA or something similar. You pass these into your custom action (if it's managed code installer class) with the argument list, something like /myinput=TEXTBOXA.

MSDN seem to have deleted the walkthroughs since these projects go away after VS 2010, so it's getting tough to find this in installer class and setup project examples and docs.